# How to join two table using with() method in laravel..?

Tags: php, laravel

I have to fetch data from two table. 
i don't want to use DB or leftjoin methods.
i want to fetch data in this manner:

```
User::with('userprofile')->where('is_active','=','1')->get();
```

i have to fetch user name , which is stored in "userprofile" table and the status of user is stored in "User" table.

thanks

Comment: So what's not working with the above? Looks fine to me, then you can loop the results and get the user name for each individual user, e.g. `$user->userprofile->username` or whatever you call it.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for [laravel relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)?

Comment: this is my original query:

user::with('userprofile')->select('id', DB::raw('CONCAT(first_name, " ", email) AS userData'))->where('is_active','=','1')->orderBy('email', 'asc')->lists('userData', 'user.id');

it will result in "column not found first_name".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the result as well using `with` this way:

```
User::with(['userprofile' => function($query){
   $query->where('is_active','=','1');
}])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved, i use join() in place of with() and now it is working fine.
eg:

```
join('userprofile', 'user.id', '=', 'userprofile.user_id')
```

thanks